# google directory api "Domain cannot use apis"

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm trying use the Google Directory API.
In my project I enabled the Admin SDK, Google+ Domains API.

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

ArrayList<String> scopeList = new ArrayList<>();
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
scopeList.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY);

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setServiceAccountId("bla-bla@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
      .setServiceAccountScopes(scopeList)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("c:/my-file.p12"))
      .setServiceAccountUser("logined-user-email")
      .build();

credential.setAccessToken(<accessToken from OAuth to google>);
Directory admin = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
          .setApplicationName("Test")
          .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();


Users users = admin.users().list().setDomain("my-domain.com").execute();
```

=>   **"Domain cannot use apis**"

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

To use Admin SDK APIs, domain admin needs to "Enable API access" in admin console. Please refer [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60757?hl=en)